# Remove empty elements from 2d array

Tags: python

For following table:

```
table = [["David, О.А.", "12651@gmail.com", "12651@gmail.com"],
         ["Lincoln, С.Е.", "qwe@mail.ru", "qwe@mail.ru"],
         [None, None, None],
         ["White, K.О.", "rak9@yahoo.com", "rak9@yahoo.com"],
         ["Pinkman, С.Е.", "mki@mail.ru", "mki@mail.ru"],
         [None, None, None]]
```

I tried to remove empty elements with this:

```
table = filter(None, table)
```

But this doesn't effect at all and the table remains same. How to get rid of empty elements to get the following output:

```
-------------  ---------------  ---------------
David, О.А.    12651@gmail.com  12651@gmail.com
Lincoln, С.Е.  qwe@mail.ru      qwe@mail.ru
White, K.О.    rak9@yahoo.com   rak9@yahoo.com
Pinkman, С.Е.  mki@mail.ru      mki@mail.ru
-------------  ---------------  ---------------
```

Comment: Any chance you tried to understand why `filter(None, table)` did not work for you in the first place or you just copied this from somewhere w/o bothering?

Comment: `table = [i for i in table if not all(j is None for j in i)]`

Comment: `filter(lambda l: all(l), table)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `python` any non-empty `list` is considered truthy so your `filter` do not remove them, use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) built-in function to allow only lists which have at least 1 truthy element that is

```
table = [["David, О.А.", "12651@gmail.com", "12651@gmail.com"],
         ["Lincoln, С.Е.", "qwe@mail.ru", "qwe@mail.ru"],
         [None, None, None],
         ["White, K.О.", "rak9@yahoo.com", "rak9@yahoo.com"],
         ["Pinkman, С.Е.", "mki@mail.ru", "mki@mail.ru"],
         [None, None, None]]
table = list(filter(any, table))
print(table)
```

output

```
[['David, О.А.', '12651@gmail.com', '12651@gmail.com'], ['Lincoln, С.Е.', 'qwe@mail.ru', 'qwe@mail.ru'], ['White, K.О.', 'rak9@yahoo.com', 'rak9@yahoo.com'], ['Pinkman, С.Е.', 'mki@mail.ru', 'mki@mail.ru']]
```